# Pairwise Swap of nodes without swapping data in LinkedList

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I have been trying to do pairwise swap of linkedlist elements. In place of swapping the elements by data, I am swapping them by swapping the links:

input 1: `1->2->3->4->5`
output 1: `2->1->4->3->5`

input 2: `1->2->3->4->5->6`
output 2: `2->1->4->3->6->5`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node* func(struct node *f, struct node *s){
    if(s==NULL){
        return f;
    }

    struct node *rest1;
    rest1 = s->next;

    s->next = f;
    if(rest1){
        f->next = func(rest1,rest1->next);
    }

    return s;
}

void show(struct node *head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        cout<<" "<<head->data;
        head = head->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    //code
    struct node *head  =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data=1;
    head->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->next->data = 2;
    head->next->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->next->next->data = 3;
    head->next->next->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->next->next->next->data = 4;
    //head->next->next->next->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //head->next->next->next->next->data=5;

    head = func(head,head->next);
    show(head);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine for odd length list but does not work for even length.
I think the problem is in:

```
if(s==NULL){
    return f;
}
```

statement which I am using to make previous `f->next=NULL` (in case of even length).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the  case of Even length list say 1->2->3->4->5->6 when **f points to 5**, **s points to 6** & **rest1 points to null**.

s->next  = f makes node 6->5 but still node 5 will point to 6. Thus a loop will be formed where 6->5->6->5..............so on.

Thus to make this code work **add an else statement** here

```
if(rest1){
        f->next = func(rest1,rest1->next);
}
else f->next = NULL;
```

This will make 5->NULL preventing an infinite loop.Thus your function will look like this

```
struct node* func(struct node *f, struct node *s){
    if(s==NULL){
        return f;
    }

    struct node *rest1;
    rest1 = s->next;

    s->next = f;
    if(rest1){
        f->next = func(rest1,rest1->next);
    }
    else f->next = NULL;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I have another doubt.  If I remove if(rest1){..} statement  & simply keep f->next = func(rest1,rest1->next); then in next recursion f->next should become NULL as if(s==NULL) will return f which is NULL . I tried this but this does not work again. Can you explain why?

Comment: This is because rest1 is null. There is no node that rest1 points to.So rest1->next will not even exist.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this as C++, I'd recommend STL's `<list>`.  You can accomplish what you want with its `splice` method which allows you to manipulate the list.  One possible implementation would look something like:

```
void alternate(list<int>& l)
{
    if (l.empty())
        return;
    auto from_itr = cbegin(l);
    auto to_itr = from_itr;
    for (; ++to_itr != cend(l) && ++to_itr != cend(l);) {
        l.splice(to_itr, l, from_itr);
        ++from_itr;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The `from_itr` in the loop is incremented only *once* because it has been moved in the list to precede the next node of interest.